# Measure query processing time in MEMSQL 6 beta

Tags: execution-time, beta, singlestore

I'm using mysql client to execute script files  like: `mysql -u root --prompt="memsql>" < file.sql`. How can I retrieve the processing time of the query?

In other systems I usually do smth like:

```
BEGIN
  start = now();
  select *, some_udf(X_ID) from X;
  end = now();
  select DATEDIFF(start, end);
END;
```

But this is somehow not possible in Memsql.

**EDIT:** It seems there is a [workload profiling](https://docs.memsql.com/v5.8/docs/management-view-reference) feature in 5.8 but this section is not there in version 6. Also the views `mv_activities`/`mv_finished_tasks` nor the system variable `read_advanced_counters` exist in my system.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a stored procedure: http://docs.memsql.com/v6.0-beta/docs/create-procedure.

Comment: I already tested this and it gave me ```'SELECT inside stored procedure as statement' is not supported```.